# GWT Grid alternative for Java

Tags: java, gwt, grid, panel, grid-layout

What is the `Java` equivalent of a `GWT Grid` (where you can insert graphical object onto coordinates x,y on the `Grid`)? I've made something in `Java` that looks like it, made by using a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, but with the addition of the `add(int x, int y)` method, to support the placement of `JButtons` and `JLabels` and such on the `Panel`. Or is there no equivalent, and is my solution the best way to insert graphical content onto such a `Panel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is closer to what you actually want. You can specify the position of your component via `GridBagConstraints`. You then add the component using the constraints.

A quick example:

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
// Position in upper left corner
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;

panel.add(component, c);
```